# Javascript - square distance having bad performance, why?

Tags: javascript, performance

For my project, I'm calculating the nearest neighbours in a quadtree and found that my square distance function was taking a lot of time compared to what I would expect (shouldn't square distances be blazing fast?). The image below is from me profiling for about 5 seconds on Chrome. 
Anyone know why the time is so high and if I'm doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as TEXT, images of code are not acceptable and require other users to rewrite the code just to answer your question

Comment: @alon you do realize that the OP posted the photo to show the execution times?

Comment: How many times was this function called? It seems as if it's not necessarily slow, just executing very often.

Comment: @JonasWilms I do, but I thought that if people need to answer then they should also be able to copy the relevant line of the code

Comment: @alon then that's what you should have said. Images are totally fine as long as the code is also posted as text.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Good point and thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

You could use the more perfomant method of [`Math.hypot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot)

> The *`Math.hypot()`* function returns the square root of the sum of squares of its arguments [...]

for getting a distance of various dimentions.

This implementation should be faster than any other custom methods.

Comment: This is blatantly incorrect. Math.hypot() is slower, especially in v8-based JS environments (Chrome, Node.js).